# Azure Cognitive search - Fuzzy search - Stay consistent between suggest api and search api

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have implemented both the suggest+autocomplete a listing page who use the search api but I cannot have consistent results between what is suggested and what I have in the listing.

So my query in suggest mode is:
https://xxx/indexes/my-index/docs/suggest?suggesterName=generalSearchSuggester&top=3&fuzzy=true&$select=sys_Id,Name,Url&search=nin&api-version=2020-06-30
This return 3 results:

- Nina
- Nina25
- Nick

And with the search api my query is:
https://xxx/indexes/my-index/docs?api-version=2020-06-30&&count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&%24skip=0&%24top=16&search=nin*~1&%24select=Name

This return 2 results:

- Nina
- Nina25

In this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggestions I see "The edit distance is 1 per query string" so I guess that this correspond to ~1 but I don't understand how to make it consistent.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

In your search example you are using a combination of a wildcard search with fuzzy search. To use [fuzzy search as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-2-fuzzy-search), remove the * from your query and specify the edit distance with the tilde character directly.

```
https://xxx/indexes/my-index/docs?api-version=2020-06-30&&count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&%24skip=0&%24top=16&search=nin~1&%24select=Name
```

This will match tokens with a spelling distance of 1.

- nin~1 (matches nina)
- nin~2 (matches nick)
- nin~3 (matches nina25)

> Fuzzy search matches on terms that are similar, including misspelled
> words. To do a fuzzy search, append the tilde ~ symbol at the end of a
> single word with an optional parameter, a value between 0 and 2, that
> specifies the edit distance. For example, blue~ or blue~1 would return
> blue, blues, and glue.

**Autocomplete vs Search**

The intent of the autocomplete suggester is to give you fuzzy suggestions on what to search for. It's telling you that you can search for either nina, nina25 or nick. When searching for these terms you will get all the results containing the token nina (or nina25 or nick).

Comment: Ok thank you for those explanations. So basically I am not able to stay consistent between the suggestion and the results right?

Comment: My point is that it's an unusual use-case and not what the autocomplete suggester and and fuzzy search is made to do. They don't operate on the same data set. The suggester provides fuzzy suggestions for the selected properties only. A fuzzy search will give you matches for all searchable tokens. Theoretically you could create an index with a data model and settings that produce the same results between the suggester and search, but you could instead just use the search.